# Magento - custom column in AdminHtml product grid which contains custom output/logic?

Tags: php, sql, magento

I want to add a new column to the "Catalog Products" grid in Magento's admin area.

The new column will be called *Currently Discounted?* or *Sale Item?* and will display "Yes" when a product's `price` is more than its `special_price` (i.e. the product is in a sale).

So far I've been able to add the `special_price` column to the grid, via the code below:

`$collection->joinAttribute('special_price', 'catalog_product/special_price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());`

```
$this->addColumn('special_price',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Special Price'),
            'type'  => 'price',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'index' => 'special_price',
    ));
```

But what I really need is another column which actually performs some kind of logic to compare the special_price and print "Yes" if it's discounted and "No" if it's not.

I've added the column but for now, obviously, it's empty because its `index` doesn't correspond to any real source of data:

```
$this->addColumn('is_sale_item',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sale Item?'),
        'type'  => 'options',
        'index' => 'is_sale_item', // <--- HOW DO I POPULATE THIS INDEX?
        'options' => array( 0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes')
));
```

How would I achieve this? Where would I put the logic for the "is_sale_item" calculation and make it a "real" index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to implement this but in a slightly hacky way. If anyone knows a better way please comment.

**1. Add the custom column to the column list, with a custom renderer and a filter callback**

```
$this->addColumn('is_sale_item',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sale Item?'),
                'type'  => 'options',
                'index' => 'is_sale_item',
                'options' => array( "no" => 'No', "yes" => 'Yes'),
                'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Sale',
                'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterIsSaleItem'),
        ));
```

**2. Create custom renderer for the new custom attribute**

I used a custom renderer to perform the logic to test whether the item has been reduced or not. Again, probably not the right way to do this. In the folder with `Grid.php`, create `Renderer/Sale.php`:

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Sale extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $_price        = $row->getData("price");
        $_specialPrice = $row->getData("special_price");
        if ($_specialPrice && $_price > $_specialPrice) {
            return "Yes";
        } else {
            return "No";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**3. Add the filter callback which will apply the logic when the filter is used**

Back in `Grid.php`:

```
protected function _filterIsSaleItem($collection, $column)
    {   
        $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();

        if (!$value) {
            return $this;
        }

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->getCollection()->joinAttribute('price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
        $this->getCollection()->joinAttribute('special_price', 'catalog_product/special_price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());

        if ($value == "yes") {
            $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("_table_price.value >  _table_special_price.value");
        } else {
            $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("_table_price.value <= _table_special_price.value OR _table_special_price.value IS NULL");
        }

        return $this;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
$this->addColumn('special_price', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Special Price'),
    'type'      => 'options',
    'index'     => 'special_price',
    'options' => Mage::getSingleton('eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean')->getOptionArray(),
));
```

@WackGet I hope you find this useful :).